# Getting a python script to acknowledge modules in a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-environment, modulenotfounderror

I have a script (personal, not for distribution) that works on one of my computers. I want edit it on another computer.

On the first computer, the script was created without a virtual environment. I want to start using them on the second computer.

I have these set up on the second computer.

- Windows 10
- VS Code 1.45.1
- Python 3.8.3

Paths:

- Python - `C:\Python38`
- Virtual environments - `C:\Users\<User>\Envs`
- Projects folders - `C:\Users\<User>\Documents\python-projects`

Environmental variable WORKON_HOME is set to virtual environments path

I copied the script to the project folder. After activating the venv with `workon`, I `pip installed` the external modules on the second computer.

I can see the modules when the virtual environment is activated and not when it is deactivated. I believe this means the virtual environment is working and the modules were properly installed.

However, I keep getting the `ModuleNotFound` error for the external modules. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the venv and the modules but I keep getting the error. To ensure it's not the computer, I deactivated the venv and installed the modules and the script worked. I even tried creating a new script with only `import requests` and I still get `ModuleNotFound`.

What do I need to do to get the script to use the modules in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multple ways. Some are listed here.

#### 1.using IDLE

```py
>>> help("modules")
```

#### 2.using PIP

```sh
$ pip list
```

#### 3.Using Anaconda

```sh
$ conda list
```

Before doing this, activate particular environment.

Comment: I don't understand how the answer relates to the issue. I already have VS Code so why do I need IDLE or Anaconda? Also, as I mentioned, the virtual environment  is activatated and I can see the list of modules installed in it. I just can't get the script to use them.


I revised the final sentence in my issue to be more specific in case it was confusing.

Comment: first check this packages are available in environment. And then try to import them.